# Fancybox popup always scrolls on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have implemented the fancybox plugin in my website, but I noticed this issue:

Every time I click an image, it opens the image correctly, but it always scrolls on top of the website, and does'nt let me scroll down when the popup is opened.
You can see this issue in my website [here](http://www.dariocanova.com/new/index.php).

I tried using the option "scrollOutside", but it doesn't work.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This was an old bug. Download the latest master from here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip and that should make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before going to my solution, notice that the scrolling is not the `fancybox` issue itself. You can basically test it through browser console in all other pages:

```
$.fancybox("test");
```

In this webpage, you have several `<div>` as scrollable pages. Maybe you can scroll back to the right page. I writ the scroll back solution.

First we need to save the page when you click it.

```
var thisPage = "homepage";
$(".page").click(function(){
    thisPage = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Now you can scroll back to the page whenever you want. For instance `onClosed`:

```
$("a.inline").fancybox({
    // ... other configurations ...
    'onClosed' : function() {
        $("html,body").scrollTop($("#"+thisPage).offset().top);
    }
});
```

Let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: It was a fancybox issue, solved in the latest master https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 0):

You have the following selector in your css, which is causing the issue.

```
html , body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

if just remove `html` here, it'll work. The thing is when 100% height is given to `<html>` tag, overflow doesn't work the way you need.

Or alternative option is give inline style to `<html>` tag and set `height: auto;`. Open your console and then try opening an image, it won't scroll to top.